# Error Trying to load http url using curl

Tags: ubuntu, curl, http, https, url

I am beginner. I am trying to load HTTP URL using curl in my Ubuntu terminal.

The command I am using is

```
curl -L 'http://google.com'
```

But instead of getting source code. I am getting below error

> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

when I change the URL to https://google.com then no error is coming and perfectly working.

Why and how to make it work even for HTTP?

Comment: Strangely, I do get a response: `$ curl -L http://google.com
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" ...` and the same for https: `$ curl -L https://google.com
<!doctype html><html itemscope=""` You can try and telnet to it on port 80 (`telnet google.co.uk 80`) and it'll hang for ages.  Type `^]` to get out of it, and you'll see a load of HTML come back. When I do the same with HTTPS (`telnet google.co.uk 443`), you don't get anything back.

Comment: Telnet on port 80: 
`$ telnet google.com 80
Trying 172.217.169.78...
Connected to google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Length: 1555`

Comment: Telnet on port 443:
`$ telnet google.com 443
Trying 172.217.169.78...
Connected to google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]

FConnection closed by foreign host.`